# Creating window executable file in linux

Tags: linux, python, window

I have written a bunch of python code. I want it to convert in the .exe file I know there is a lib(pyinstaller) for this but it works on window only if I use on terminal it convert the code into linux executable file. I want to know that is there any way by which i can convert python code into exe file in linux?

Comment: Have you try to run windows executable in Wine?

Comment: The file which is generated is linux executable not window executable

Comment: Real problem: I want to create a .exe file for windows of some python code in linux

Comment: @RoVo It seems that the second answer uses pyinstaller as well. Perhaps the process in the second answer may be used with py2exe as well.